# Show that the function $x\mapsto x\sin x$ is continuous at $x = 0$

Tags: calculus, continuity

> Use the definition of continuity to show that the function: $f: \mathbb R \to\mathbb R$ defined by $f(x) = x\sin x$ is continuous at $x = 0$.

**Def:** A real valued function $f$  is called  continuous at $a \in \mathbb R$ if the $\lim_{x \to a}f(x) = f(a)$

So continuous if $\lim_{x \to 0}x\sin x = f(0) = 0\sin 0 = 0$

By inspection when $x = 0$,  $x\sin x = 0\sin 0 = 0\cdot0 = 0$

Which means $f$ is continuous at $0$.

Comment: Do you know __the definition of continuity__?

Comment: My guess would be that they want something a little more first principles than this but maybe not. If they do want something more first principles, I would suggest using the squeeze theorem.

Comment: Oh typo how's this Portakal? I meant to say the F(x) is continuous at "a" ir  $\lim_{x \to a}F(x) = F(a)$

Comment: __The definition of continuity:__ A function $f$ is continuous at a point $a$ if for every $\varepsilon >0$, there exists $\delta >0$ such that $|x-a| < \delta$ implies that $|f(x) - f(a)| < \varepsilon$

Comment: I just don't understand why if this is the definition of continuity, how does my original answer fit into the picture? How do i use this to work with gamma and delta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $|\sin x|\leqslant 1$ for all $x$. So given $\varepsilon>0$, if $|x|<\varepsilon$, then $$|x\sin x| \leqslant |x| <\varepsilon$$
which means that $x\mapsto x\sin x$ is continuous at $0$.